# Delivering a Linux application icon without installer / package manager

Tags: linux, icons

**Backstory:**

I want to:

1. Deliver an application as a simple TAR that users extract and run
2. For that app to have a proper app icon.

***No package manger, no sudo, no installer script.***

I see from the [standard](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#install_icons) and [various articles](https://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/) that app icons require a `.desktop` file which needs the absolute paths to the executable (ugh) and app icon. I also see that Ubuntu Unity (perhaps others) supports `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`

Windows supports this by embedding icons into executables. Mac OS X has a relative directory structure for applications that includes the icon.

**“Hackish” solution:**

My “hackish” solution is, at app startup, detect whether `myApp.desktop` file exists in `~/.local/share/applications/`, and if not, write it (including full absolute path to executable and icon), launch a new myApp process and exit.

The hope is, the new myApp process will pick up the app icon. and *sometimes* it does.

**The Problem:**

This problem is, I have to `sleep 2` seconds before launching the new process. If I do, the icon is picked up. If I don't, there is no icon for my app.

I’ve tried reloading the GTK icon cache instead of sleeping (with `gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor`) but that doesn't do the trick.

Anybody know how I can avoid this delay and ensure the newly written `.desktop` file gets picked up? (I am flushing and closing the file.) Or have a better idea than my hackish solution?

**Update:** Interesting, testing a plain script that writes the `.desktop` file (either manually or with [xdg-desktop-menu](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-desktop-menu)) and launches the application, it also needs a 2 second delay or the icon won't show up. Fascinating.

Comment: If you want to install for all users, you will need root privileges to copy files into the `/usr` directory unless you either use non-standard paths for shared software or allow write access to areas which are normally read/execute only. You may like to investigate the `.bundle` format used by VMware and others, though I cannot recall whether it prompts for a password.

Comment: "If you want to install for all users, you will need root privileges to copy files into the /usr directory" -- right, and if I go ahead and make an installer script, it might ask, then setup the .desktop file. But I don't like installer scripts, esp those downloaded form the Internet asking for root. Hence my request for "extract and run" simplicity. If `.bundle` format is like a self-extracting installer, I'd consider an installer script, so I'd prefer to avoid it. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I've installed the VMware `.bundle` several times and was impressed with how smoothly it all went. It seems to handle all the different flavours of Linux, rather than `.deb`, `.rpm`, etc, which are tied to particular distribution groups. It is basically a huge script file with embedded binaries, and there must be tools to build it. So it _is_ an installer script, but a pretty flexible one - and it did seamlessly add the desk-top and application menu short-cuts. A `tar` archive would need to be extracted in a known place: I'm pretty sure you can't use paths like `$HOME/` within it.

Comment: Not using packages is bad style. Usually you should provide rpm and deb at least.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gtk_window_set_icon](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-icon) or similar (there's a _from_file variant, and Glade integration).

Without root, I don't think you have access to the icon cache, and timely loading of the desktop file doesn't seem to be a reliable method as you've discovered.